# DocuSign: Embedded signing on website after creating custom pdf

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, docusignapi

I am using DocuSign API to get signatures from my clients.

**Scenario:**

Client filled up whole form and right before success redirection I want them to sign that pdf document at specific place.

The PDF file will be dynamically generated for each user on runtime.

How exactly it can be done? What should be the steps on it?

The platform is ruby on rails. I couldn't find exact documentation on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not very familiar with Ruby, but I can explain the general process for implementing the DocuSign API scenario you've described. You can then leverage this info along with the [DocuSign Ruby SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client) to achieve your goal. (It seems like the [unit tests](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-ruby-client/blob/master/tests/spec/unit_tests_spec.rb) within the Ruby SDK repo contains some sample code that may be useful to you.)

The scenario you've described requires that you issue 2 API requests:

1. **Create Envelope** request (specifying an embedded/captive recipient)
2. **Get Recipient View** request

First, use the DocuSign API to issue a **[Create Envelope](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/)** request.

- As part of the request, you'll specify recipient info, tab info (to indicate where the recipient needs to sign the document), and the document bytes.
- Within the recipient info, be sure to include the `clientUserId` property, which will designate the recipient as an [embedded/captive recipient](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/guide/usage/embedded_signing.html) -- this is critical for your scenario.
- Within the `tabs` property of the `signer` (recipient) object, you'll specify a `signHereTab` for each location where the recipient should sign the document, using `documentId`, `pageNumber`, `xPosition`, and `yPosition` to specify the location of each tab.

The following example shows a **Create Envelope** request that contains a single document, one embedded/captive recipient (signer), and one signature tab (which appears on the first page of the document at position with x/y coordinates 25/25).

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes
{
    "status": "sent",
    "emailSubject":"Please Sign",
    "recipients": {
      "signers": [
          {
              "name": "John Doe",
              "email": "john.doe@test.com",
              "recipientId": "1",
              "clientUserId": "12345",
              "tabs": {
                  "signHereTabs": [
                      {
                         "xPosition":25,
                         "yPosition":25,
                         "documentId":1,
                         "pageNumber":1
                      }
                  ]
              }
          }
      ]
    },
    "documents": [
        {
            "documentId": "1",
            "documentBase64": "DOCUMENT_BYTES_HERE",
            "fileExtension": "pdf",
            "name": "FILENAME.pdf"

        }
    ]
}
```

Once you receive the **Create Envelope** response, indicating that the Envelope was successfully created, immediately issue a **[Get Recipient View](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient/)** request. The response will contain a URL that you can redirect the user to complete their signing ceremony via the DocuSign web UI.

The following example shows a **Get Recipient View** request corresponding to the Envelope (and recipient) specified in the previous example.

```
POST /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/views/recipient
{
    "authenticationMethod": "Email",
    "email": "john.doe@test.com",
    "returnUrl": "www.google.com",
    "userName": "John Doe",
    "clientUserId": "12345"
}
```

Comment: You really helped in achieving what I was looking for. I was so close to my integration using same process but got stumbled due to some other reasons. :)

Answer (score 1):

As Kim mentioned you need to use embedded signing for your use case. You need to follow one of the following strategies to know where to place the DS Tabs for getting the signature:

- By using X/Y Position on the PDF Doc, example shared in the Kim's
  post
- By using Anchor String, you place hidden text on the PDF then you
  pass these hidden text in DS API calls and informs DS which tabs to
  place for these hidden texts. Details are available at [Anchoring
  Tabs](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Tabs/Anchoring%20Tabs.htm) and [Anchoring Rules](https://www.docusign.com/p/APIGuide/Content/Sending%20Group/Rules%20for%20Anchor%20Tagging.htm). Examples are available [here](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/autoplace)
- If you are creating PDF form fields as per DS Standards, then you can
  directly convert PDF fields to DS Tabs as explained [here](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Document%20Parameters.htm#Transfor)